# Route dynamic URLs to static files in App Engine Java

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, go

I have a **Java App Engine** app and want to route `mydomain.com/i/<anything>` to `i.html`. For example:

```
mydomain.com/i/12345 --> i.html

mydomain.com/i/abcde --> i.html
```

This looks like it is possible to do in [app.yaml for Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers) and [app.yaml for Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig) with something like:

```
handlers:
  - url: /i/(.*)
    static_files: i.html
```

but this handler mapping to static files is NOT mentioned in [app.yaml for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/configyaml/appconfig_yaml#Java_app_yaml_The_welcome_file_list). Instead, there is a separate **Static files and resource files** section that cannot do url mappings, and the only options to map a url in `handlers` is to a `servlet`, `jsp`, or `filter`. If I try to map to `static_files` in a Java app.yaml, I get an `Unable to find property 'static_files'` error.

The key here is that I want to **map a url to a static file that is served as a static file**. Why would this be only possible to do in Python and Go, and not in Java?

Answer (score 1):

I dont use the java version but it looks like the `appengine-web.xml` serves the same function as the app.yaml in go / python?

Comment: For Java GAE, there is the option to instead generate `appengine-web.xml` and `web.xml` from an `app.yaml`. I chose this option hoping I could do url routing to a static file, but for some reason, it seems this feature is only available in Python and Go GAE.